# best database design with shared data and multiple application

Tags: web-services, laravel, database-design, architecture, multi-tenant

I am in an Enterprise environment.

I have to design an HRM database (Human Resource Management).

This database must contain information for each employee (ie. Name, Last Name, Company, etc.).

To this database it must be connected to several applications.

Each of these applications performs different functions and manages other data to associate with the HRM database (ie. courses, activities, vehicles, etc.).

Each application is managed by some users.

Each application must have the possibility to create a new "employee record" in the HRM database.

A general scheme is the following:

[General scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwXWb.jpg)

**Q**: What is the best **database design** and **software architecture** to do this?

I would use *Laravel* as a framework for each application and *PostgreSQL* as database.

Comment: What you are you looking for exactly. Database design??

Comment: Yes, both database design and software architecture. Thanks

Comment: Okay, can you please update your question to describe exactly what you are looking for in your database design?

Comment: and what have you done so far

Answer (score 0):

> Q: What is the best database design and software architecture to do this?

I think database design and software architecture depend on the framework, `Laravel`. At first, I recommend you to read a document: [Laravel 4.2 Laravel Quickstart - Eloquent ORM](https://readouble.com/laravel/4.2/en/quick.html#eloquent-orm)

**database design**

[ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), it means tables are abstracted by the framework. To represent data models, you should consider about what is required data models (= table).

To design data models, at first you need to check required real world **Requirement** ( for example, `users` table must have `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`.)

After that, please check a kind of ActiveRecord pettern from this article: [Active record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern). Because Laravel is based on Ruby on Rails's activerecord.

**FYI**

- [Mapping Objects to Relational Databases: O/R Mapping In Detail](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html)

**software architecture**

TBD